# Win10 Batch script: \Notepad++ was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file

This batch file gives the error in the title:

```
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (
    echo FOOBAR
) else (
    set HOME_EDIT=%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++
)
```

This is on a Win10 Pro x64 system (so the test is false).

Strangely the "set HOME_EDIT..." line, if executed by itself, does NOT generate the error. And this batch file seemed to work OK a few weeks ago (oldest complaint in the book, I know, but maybe the recent Win10 Creator's Update chagned something?).

Here's the whole output:

```
U:\Users\Dave\data\PC setup\2017-03 PC Setup for Win10>test.bat
\Notepad++ was unexpected at this time.

U:\Users\Dave\data\PC setup\2017-03 PC Setup for Win10>    set HOME_EDIT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++

U:\Users\Dave\data\PC setup\2017-03 PC Setup for Win10>
```

Comment: You need to use quotes since there is a space in the path.

Comment: @drescherjm It seems you're right, since it works with the quotes. But it works WITHOUT the quotes if the SET is on a line by itself. Grrr I hate batch files. Make it an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: `set HOME_EDIT="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting quotes around the assignment certainly solves the problem, but it has nothing to do with spaces. The problem is the `)` in the path is closing the ELSE block prematurely unless the path is quoted (or escaped).

Without quotes, the ELSE block becomes

```
) else (
    set HOME_EDIT=%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86
)
```

And then the `\Notepad++` is indeed unexpected, causing a syntax error.

I see 3 ways to eliminate the syntax error:

1) Eliminate the parentheses and put the SET command on the same line as ELSE

```
else set HOME_EDIT=%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++
```

2) Put quotes around the assignment

```
) else (
    set "HOME_EDIT=%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++"
)
```

3) Escape the closing parenthesis

```
) else (
    set HOME_EDIT=%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86^)\Notepad++
)
```

If I were to do the assignment, I would use the predefined environment variable for the folder.

```
) else (
    set "HOME_EDIT=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

@drescherjm was correct (in the comments) that the immediate problem was lack of quote marks ("foo") around the argument to SET. Somehow this matters when the SET is within a IF statement, even tho it doesn't otherwise.

But adding quotes just broke something else later in my batch script:

```
set NEW_PATH=%HOME_WINDOWS%
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%BinPath%
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%BinPath%\ffmpeg\bin
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%BinPath%\mplayer
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%BinPath%\gui
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%BinPath%\dll
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%HOME_CYGWIN%\bin
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%HOME_CYGWIN%\sbin
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%HOME_CYGWIN%\usr\bin
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%HOME_CYGWIN%\usr\sbin
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%HOME_7ZIP%
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%HOME_EDIT%
set NEW_PATH=%NEW_PATH%;%HOME_DIFF%

set Path=%NEW_PATH%
setx Path "%NEW_PATH%"
```

If HOME_EDIT has quote marks in it, this causes SETX to fail.

Here's the fix I came up with (note lines marked with "TRICK1"):

```
REM The following is a trick to get around spaces in the path (TRICK1)
set HOME_EDIT=%SystemDrive%\%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++

if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" ( 
    set HOME_CYGWIN=%SystemDrive%\cygwin
    set HOME_EDIT=%SystemDrive%\Program Files\Notepad++
) else (
    set HOME_CYGWIN=%SystemDrive%\cygwin64
    REM (TRICK1 rem this out) set HOME_EDIT=%SystemDrive%\%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++
)
```

The path with the spaces in it is SET as a default value prior to entering the IF statement. This way no quote marks are needed, and SETX doesn't break later.

Comment: You appear to be forcing the path for Notepad++ to the location for 32bit executables on your 64bit systems, is that really what you wanted? A 64bit OS runs a 64bit executable from Program Files; A 32bit OS runs a 32bit executable from Program Files; A 64bit OS runs a 32bit executable from Program Files (x86).

Comment: @Compo Yes, that's the intent. I run 32 bit Notepad++ on both x86 and x64 machines.

Comment: It seems a little odd to force such a thing. Also are you aware that `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` simply returning `x86` does not mean that you are not running a 64bit OS? _(you may be forcing the use of a 32bit version of cygwin on some 64bit systems too!)_